# JPA + Wildfly + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly

Existe algum jeito de alterar dinamicamente a conexão com o banco de dados alterando o arquivo *standalone.xml* do *Wildfly 8 (ou 10)*? Atualmente eu tenho uma classe *HibernateSessionFactory* que cria u*m EntityManagerFactory* com os parâmetros de conexão a partir de um arquivo *.properties*:

```
    try {
        Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String valor = "jdbc:sqlserver:" + pGetServer()
                + ";databaseName=%s";
        parametros.put(PERSISTENCE, String.format(valor, pGetDataBase()));
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                "BANCO", parametros);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating entityManagerFactory %%%%");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**persistence.xml**:

```
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider" />
    </properties>
```

Comment: Posta o seu .properties, acho que você pode ler o arquivo dinamicamente. É alterar sua conexão. Em qual situação você quer altera sua conexão.

Comment: Esse é ponto. Eu já pego a conexão de lá. A ideia é não pegar as informações de conexões de lá, mas sim do arquivo standalone.xml do WildFly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Conexao com SQLServer -->
<persistence-unit name="nome-persistence1" transaction-type="JTA">

    <jta-data-source>conexao1</jta-data-source>

     <class>entidade</class>

   <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>

<!-- Conexao com oracle -->
<persistence-unit name="nome-persistence2" transaction-type="JTA">

    <jta-data-source>java:/conexao2</jta-data-source>

     <class>entidade</class>

   <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Você deve apontar para a sua configuração de **DataSource do  Wildfly 8**! Que deve ficar mais o menos a sim a depender do seu servidor de aplicação.

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/conexao1" pool-name="conexao1" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>url</connection-url>
    <driver>SQLServerDriver</driver>
    <!--configuração do DataSource do  Wildfly 8 -->
</datasource>

<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/conexao2" pool-name="conexao2" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>url</connection-url>
    <driver>oracleDriver</driver>
    <!--configuração do DataSource do  Wildfly 8 -->
</datasource>
```

Comment: Você pode fazer a sim se isso te ajudar!!

Answer (score 0):

> Existe algum jeito de alterar dinamicamente a conexão com o banco de dados alterando o arquivo standalone.xml do Wildfly 8 (ou 10)?

Se entendi certo, você quer trabalhar com mais de um banco de dados, certo?

Se sim, acho mais fácil você criar um datasource no `standalone.xml` e uma unidade de persistência no `persistence.xml` para cada conexão separadamente e escolher com qual trabalhar no momento de criar o `EntityManagerFactory`.

Por exemplo:

---

**standalone.xml:**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/dataSource1" pool-name="dataSource1">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/banco1</connection-url>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>usuario1</user-name>
        <password>senha1</password>
    </security>
</datasource>

<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/dataSource2" pool-name="dataSource2">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/banco2</connection-url>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>usuario2</user-name>
        <password>senha2</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

---

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit1">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jboss/datasources/dataSource1</non-jta-data-source>
</persistence-uni>

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit2">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jboss/datasources/dataSource2</non-jta-data-source>
</persistence-uni>
```

---

**Classe utilitária de JPA:**

```
if (condicao) {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit1"); 
} else {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit2"); 
}
```

Comment: Resolvi de um jeito diferente, mas isso também seria ótima opção! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pessoal, pela ajuda! Eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

- Adicionei a conexão padrão no arquivo persistence.xml:

  ```
  <persistence-unit name="Persistence-unit">
      <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver:SERVIDORX;databaseName=BASEX" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USER" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD" />
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
          <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider" />
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  ```
- Adicionei um datasource no arquivo standalone.xml:

  ```
          <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DataSource" pool-name="DataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
              <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver:SERVIDORY;databaseName=BANCOY;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
              <driver>sqlServer</driver>
              <security>
                  <user-name>USER</user-name>
                  <password>PASSWORD</password>
              </security>
          </datasource>
          <drivers>
              ...
              <driver name="sqlServer" module="jdbc.sqlServer">
                  <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
              </driver>
          </drivers>
  ```
- Na classe do Hibernate:

  ```
  Context contexto = new InitialContext();
  Connection conexao = null;
  DataSource dataSource = null;
  String server = "";
  String dataBase = "";
  try {   
      dataSource = (DataSource)contexto.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/DataSource");
      conexao = dataSource.getConnection();
      server = conexao.getMetaData().getURL().split(";")[0].split(":")[2];
      dataBase = conexao.getMetaData().getURL().split(";")[15].split("=")[1];
      Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
      parametros.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url","jdbc:sqlserver:" + server + ";databaseName=" + dataBase);
      entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistence-unit",parametros);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistence-unit");
  } finally {
      if ((conexao != null) && (!conexao.isClosed())) {
          conexao.close();
      }
  }
  ```